# Perl's caller() function returning incorrect line number

Tags: perl

I've got the following script running on Perl 5.10.1:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach( my $x =0 ; $x < 1; $x++) {   # Line 5
  print_line();                       # Line 6
} 

sub print_line {
  print "Function call from line: " . [caller(0)]->[2] . "\n";
}
```

Despite the call to the subroutine coming from line 6, the script outputs the line number of the start of the C-style for statement:

```
Function call from line: 5
```

What's really weird is if I throw a random statement into one of the blank line in the C-style for loop, `caller` returns the correct line number:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach( my $x =0 ; $x < 1; $x++) {
  my $x = 3;
  print_line();  # Line 7
}

sub print_line {
  print "Function call from line: " . [caller(0)]->[2] . "\n";
}
```

The above script correctly outputs:

```
Function call from line: 7
```

Is this some kind of bug or is there something I can do to get `caller` to accurately report the line number?

Comment: Interesting - yes, this seems to be the case. Looks like it returns the line number of the 'loop'. The `__LINE__` macro may help troubleshoot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ perl -MO=Concise a.pl
j  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
1     <0> enter ->2
2     <;> nextstate(main 6 a.pl:5) v:*,&,{,x*,x&,x$,$ ->3
5     <2> sassign vKS/2 ->6
3        <$> const[IV 0] s ->4
4        <0> padsv[$x:3,5] sRM*/LVINTRO ->5
6     <0> unstack v* ->7
i     <2> leaveloop vK/2 ->j
7        <{> enterloop(next->b last->i redo->8) v ->e
-        <1> null vK/1 ->i
h           <|> and(other->8) vK/1 ->i
g              <2> lt sK/2 ->h
e                 <0> padsv[$x:3,5] s ->f
f                 <$> const[IV 1] s ->g
-              <@> lineseq vK ->-
-                 <@> scope vK ->b                       <---
-                    <0> ex-nextstate v ->8              <---
a                    <1> entersub[t5] vKS/TARG,2 ->b
-                       <1> ex-list K ->a
8                          <0> pushmark s ->9
-                          <1> ex-rv2cv sK/2 ->-
9                             <#> gv[*print_line] s/EARLYCV ->a
c                 <1> preinc[t2] vK/1 ->d
b                    <0> padsv[$x:3,5] sRM ->c
d                 <0> unstack v ->e
a.pl syntax OK
```

There's some optimization going on. The `scope` was deemed unnecessary and optimized away. (Notice the "`-`" meaning it's never reached.)

But at the same time, that removed the `nextstate` op, which is what sets the line number for warnings and for `caller`.

So, it's a bug that results from an improper optimization.

Answer (score 7):

I think potentially it is a bug, because the same behavior doesn't occur if you replace

```
foreach (my $x = 0 ; $x < 1 ; $x++) {
```

with

```
foreach my $x (0 .. 0) {
```

I don't understand *exactly* what's happening, but by comparing the optrees of the two different versions, I think that a `nextstate` op is getting improperly optimized out. My version has

```
<;> nextstate(main 4 lineno.pl:11) v:*,&,x*,x&,x$,$ ->8
```

as the left sibling of the `entersub` op that calls `print_line`, while yours has

```
<0> ex-nextstate v ->8
```

which has been taken out of the flow of execution.

It wouldn't hurt to write this up as a [perlbug](http://p3rl.org/perlbug).

Comment: Good spot. Interesting. What are you using to extract the optimisations of the code?

Comment: Although I can't see it written up, it looks like this is a bug that has been fixed. Perl 5 version 20 doesn't display this behaviour.

Comment: @Borodin funny, I suspected that so the first thing I did was test with 5.20 — and I still see it. I wonder what's different.

Comment: I ran mine one Windows, and you're probably on Linux? Although I can't imagine how that would make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this may be down to statement separators (semicolons). As you may have spotted - with the code you're running, the line number reported by `caller` is the same as the `foreach` loop.

So I *think* what is happening, is because there's no semicolons.

If you were to do a multi-line sub call, `caller` would report the first line:

```
print "first call:", __LINE__, "\n";
print "Start of statement\n",
"a bit more on line ", __LINE__, "\n",
print_line(
    1,

    2,

    3,

    5,

);
```

You get the line number of the start of the call, not the end. So I think that's what you're getting - the statement starts when the semicolon statement separator occurs - which is the `foreach` line in the first example.

So as a workaround - I might suggest making use of [`__LINE__`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/__LINE__.html). Although I'd also perhaps suggest not worrying about it *too* much, because it's still going to point you to the right place in the code.

You get something similar if you use `croak`, for presumably the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out this is really a bug in Perl going back at least to 5.10 or 11 years, but in reality I think longer.

It has been reported as Perl bug [perl #133239](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=133239) and although it is alleged that it is not *that* hard to fix, it hasn't been. It may not also be that *easy* to fix, has performance ramifications since adding COP's slows things down, and possibly some administrative work would be needed to adjust tests.

And even if this bug were fixed, it would be only fixed in versions Perl 5.29 and later, or so. This isn't going to help you with 5.10.

So here is another tack that doesn't rely on a change to Perl's core, and therefore puts users more in control. However, I'll say up front it is a bit experimental and unless people are willing to spend coding effort on it, it's not likely to go back as far as 5.10. Right now the earliest Perl version I have working is 5.14, 7 years ago as if this writing.

Using [B::DeparseTree](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/B-DeparseTree/lib/B/DeparseTree.pod) you can write a different, and I think better *caller()* which can show you the location of the caller with more detail. Here is your program modified to do that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use B::DeparseTree::Fragment;
use Devel::Callsite;

sub dt_caller
{
    my $level = $_ ? $_ : 0;
    # Pick up the right caller's OP address.
    my $addr =  callsite($level+1);
    # Hack alert 'main::main' should be replaced with the function name if not the top level. caller() is a little off-sync here.
    my $op_info = deparse_offset('main::main', $addr);
    # When Perl is in the middle of call, it has already advanced the PC,
    # so we need to go back to the preceding op. 
    $op_info = get_prev_addr_info($op_info);
    my $extract_texts = extract_node_info($op_info);
    print join("\n", @$extract_texts), "\n";
}

foreach( my $x =0 ; $x < 1; $x++) {
  print_line();
}

sub print_line {
    dt_caller();
}
```

When run it prints:

```
$ perl bug-caller.pl
print_line()
------------
```

*dt_caller()* could and should be wrapped up into a package like Carp so you don't see all of that ugliness. However I'll leave that for someone else. And I'll mention that just to get this working, there were some bug fixes I had to make, so this works only starting with version 3.4.0 of *B::DeparseTree*.