# How to get the current line number in a multi-line list initializer of testcases?

Tags: list, perl, debugging, eval, stack-trace

Is there a way to reliably get the current line number during a Perl
multiline list assignment without explicitly using `__LINE__`?  I am
storing testcases in a list and would like to tag each with its line
number.*  That way I can do (roughly)
`ok($_->[1], 'line ' . $_->[0]) for @tests`.
And, of course, I would like to save typing compared to
putting `__LINE__` at the beginning of each test case :) .  I have
not been able to find a way to do so, and I have encountered some
confusing behaviour in the lines reported by `caller`.

<sup>* Possible XY, but I can't find a module to do it.</sup>

**Update** I found a hack and posted it as [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50516105/2877364).  Thanks to @zdim for helping me think about the problem a different way!

**MCVE**

A long one, because I've tried several different options.  `my_eval`,
`L()`, and `L2{}` are some I've tried so far — `L()` was the one
I initially hoped would work.  Jump down to `my @testcases` to see how
I'm using these.  When testing, do copy the shebang line.

<sup>Here's my [non-MCVE use case](https://github.com/cxw42/perlpp/blob/capture-tests/t/03-cmdline.t), if you are interested.</sup>

```
#!perl
use strict; use warnings; use 5.010;

# Modified from https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/06/set-the-line-number-and-filename-of-string-evals/#comment-155 by http://sites.google.com/site/shawnhcorey/
sub my_eval {
    my ( $expr ) = @_;
    my ( undef, $file, $line ) = caller;
    my $code = "# line $line \"$file\"\n" . $expr;

    unless(defined wantarray) {
        eval $code; die $@ if $@;
    } elsif(wantarray) {
        my @retval = eval $code; die $@ if $@; return @retval;
    } else {
        my $retval = eval $code; die $@ if $@; return $retval;
    }
}

sub L {     # Prepend caller's line number
    my (undef, undef, $line) = caller;
    return ["$line", @_];
} #L

sub L2(&) {     # Prepend caller's line number
    my $fn = shift;
    my (undef, undef, $line) = caller;
    return ["$line", &$fn];
} #L2

# List of [line number, item index, expected line number, type]
my @testcases = (
    ([__LINE__,0,32,'LINE']),
    ([__LINE__,1,33,'LINE']),
    (L(2,34,'L()')),
    (L(3,35,'L()')),
    (do { L(4,36,'do {L}') }),
    (do { L(5,37,'do {L}') }),
    (eval { L(6,38,'eval {L}') }),
    (eval { L(7,39,'eval {L}') }),
    (eval "L(8,40,'eval L')"),
    (eval "L(9,41,'eval L')"),
    (my_eval("L(10,42,'my_eval L')")),
    (my_eval("L(11,43,'my_eval L')")),
    (L2{12,44,'L2{}'}),
    (L2{13,45,'L2{}'}),
);

foreach my $idx (0..$#testcases) {
    printf "%2d %-10s line %2d expected %2d %s\n",
            $idx, $testcases[$idx]->[3], $testcases[$idx]->[0],
            $testcases[$idx]->[2],
            ($testcases[$idx]->[0] != $testcases[$idx]->[2]) && '*';
}
```

**Output**

With my comments added.

```
 0 LINE       line 32 expected 32
 1 LINE       line 33 expected 33
```

Using `__LINE__` expressly works fine, but I'm looking for an
abbreviation.

```
 2 L()        line 45 expected 34 *
 3 L()        line 45 expected 35 *
```

`L()` uses `caller` to get the line number, and reports a line *later
in the file* (!).

```
 4 do {L}     line 36 expected 36
 5 do {L}     line 45 expected 37 *
```

When I wrap the `L()` call in a `do{}`, `caller` returns the correct
line number — but only once (!).

```
 6 eval {L}   line 38 expected 38
 7 eval {L}   line 39 expected 39
```

Block `eval`, interestingly, works fine.  However, it's no shorter
than `__LINE__`.

```
 8 eval L     line  1 expected 40 *
 9 eval L     line  1 expected 41 *
```

String `eval` gives the line number inside the `eval` (no surprise)

```
10 my_eval L  line 45 expected 42 *
11 my_eval L  line 45 expected 43 *
```

`my_eval()` is a string `eval` plus a `#line` directive based on
`caller`.  It also gives a line number later in the file (!).

```
12 L2{}       line 45 expected 44 *
13 L2{}       line 45 expected 45
```

`L2` is the same as `L`, but it takes a block that returns a list,
rather than
the list itself.  It also uses `caller` for the line number.  And it
is correct once, but not twice (!).  (Possibly just because it's the last
item — `my_eval` reported line 45 also.)

**So,** what is going on here?  I have heard of Deparse and wonder if this is
optimization-related, but I don't know enough about the engine to know
where to start investigating.  I also imagine this could be done with source
filters or [`Devel::Declare`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Declare), but that is well beyond my
level of experience.

### Take 2

@zdim's answer got me started thinking about fluent interfaces, e.g., as in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50516105/2877364):

```
$testcases2     # line 26
    ->add(__LINE__,0,27,'LINE')
    ->add(__LINE__,1,28,'LINE')
    ->L(2,29,'L()')
    ->L(3,30,'L()')
    ->L(3,31,'L()')
;
```

However, even those don't work here — I get line 26 for each of the `->L()` calls.  So it appears that `caller` sees all of the chained calls as coming from the `$testcases2->...` line.  Oh well.  I'm still interested in knowing why, if anyone can enlighten me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** This answer is now wrapped in a [CPAN module](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::AutoNumbered) ([GitHub](https://github.com/cxw42/List-AutoNumbered))!

---

[@zdim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50515253/2877364) got me thinking about fluent interfaces.  Below are **two hacks** that work for my particular use case, but that don't help me understand the behaviour reported in the question.  If you can help, please post another answer!

### Hack 2 (newer) *(the one now on CPAN)*

I think this one is very close to minimal.  In perl, you can call a subroutine through a reference with `$ref->()`, and you can leave out the second and subsequent `->` in a chain of arrows.  That means, for example, that you can do:

```
my $foo; $foo=sub { say shift; return $foo; };
$foo->(1)
      (2)
      (3);
```

Looks good, right?  So here's the MCVE:

```
#!perl
use strict; use warnings; use 5.010;

package FluentAutoIncList2 {
    sub new {   # call as $class->new(__LINE__); each element is one line
        my $class = shift;
        my $self = bless {lnum => shift // 0, arr => []}, $class;

        # Make a loader that adds an item and returns itself --- not $self
        $self->{loader} = sub { $self->L(@_); return $self->{loader} };

        return $self;
    }
    sub size { return scalar @{ shift->{arr} }; }
    sub last { return shift->size-1; }      # $#

    sub load { goto &{ shift->{loader} } }  # kick off loading

    sub L {     # Push a new record with the next line number on the front
        my $self = shift;
        push @{ $self->{arr} }, [++$self->{lnum}, @_];
        return $self;
    } #L

    sub add {   # just add it
        my $self = shift;
        ++$self->{lnum};    # keep it consistent
        push @{ $self->{arr} }, [@_];
        return $self;
    } #add

} #FluentAutoIncList2

# List of [line number, item index, expected line number, type]
my $testcases = FluentAutoIncList2->new(__LINE__)    # line 28
    ->add(__LINE__,0,36,'LINE')
    ->add(__LINE__,1,37,'LINE');
    $testcases->load(2,38,'load')->     # <== Only need two arrows.
    (3,39,'chain load')                 # <== After that, () are enough.
    (4,40,'chain load')
    (5,41,'chain load')
    (6,42,'chain load')
    (7,43,'chain load')
;

foreach my $idx (0..$testcases->last) {
    printf "%2d %-10s line %2d expected %2d %s\n",
            $idx, $testcases->{arr}->[$idx]->[3],
            $testcases->{arr}->[$idx]->[0],
            $testcases->{arr}->[$idx]->[2],
            ($testcases->{arr}->[$idx]->[0] !=
                $testcases->{arr}->[$idx]->[2]) && '*';
}
```

Output:

```
 0 LINE       line 36 expected 36
 1 LINE       line 37 expected 37
 2 load       line 38 expected 38
 3 chain load line 39 expected 39
 4 chain load line 40 expected 40
 5 chain load line 41 expected 41
 6 chain load line 42 expected 42
 7 chain load line 43 expected 43
```

All the `chain load` lines were loaded with zero extra characters compared to the original `[x, y]` approach.  Some overhead, but not much!

### Hack 1

Code:

By starting with `__LINE__` and assuming a fixed number of lines per call, a counter will do the trick.  This could probably be done more cleanly with a `tie`.

```
#!perl
use strict; use warnings; use 5.010;

package FluentAutoIncList {
    sub new {   # call as $class->new(__LINE__); each element is one line
        my $class = shift;
        return bless {lnum => shift // 0, arr => []}, $class;
    }
    sub size { return scalar @{ shift->{arr} }; }
    sub last { return shift->size-1; }      # $#

    sub L {     # Push a new record with the next line number on the front
        my $self = shift;
        push @{ $self->{arr} }, [++$self->{lnum}, @_];
        return $self;
    } #L

    sub add {   # just add it
        my $self = shift;
        ++$self->{lnum};    # keep it consistent
        push @{ $self->{arr} }, [@_];
        return $self;
    } #add

} #FluentAutoIncList

# List of [line number, item index, expected line number, type]
my $testcases = FluentAutoIncList->new(__LINE__)    # line 28
    ->add(__LINE__,0,29,'LINE')
    ->add(__LINE__,1,30,'LINE')
    ->L(2,31,'L()')
    ->L(3,32,'L()')
    ->L(4,33,'L()')
;

foreach my $idx (0..$testcases->last) {
    printf "%2d %-10s line %2d expected %2d %s\n",
            $idx, $testcases->{arr}->[$idx]->[3],
            $testcases->{arr}->[$idx]->[0],
            $testcases->{arr}->[$idx]->[2],
            ($testcases->{arr}->[$idx]->[0] !=
                $testcases->{arr}->[$idx]->[2]) && '*';
}
```

Output:

```
 0 LINE       line 29 expected 29
 1 LINE       line 30 expected 30
 2 L()        line 31 expected 31
 3 L()        line 32 expected 32
 4 L()        line 33 expected 33
```

Comment: Very interesting (+1-ed back then), but also from what I see your "second hack" works, too -- the question's end still says that it doesn't. Perhaps the question text needs update?

Comment: Also, this seems to solve the stated problem, so please accept it :)))

Comment: @zdim I accepted yours since it explains the behaviour.  Also, I have a bit of work to do before these hacks are production-ready :) .  (Question text updated, too.)

Comment: Oh, thank you -- that absolutely obliges me to find a(nother) way to actually do what the question asks :).  I'll look more.  If you do wrap this "hack" up to your liking please update, it is interesting (and change the accept :))

Comment: @zdim :D :D --- The big worklist item for me is to add a `skip()` so that I can put comments in the list.  Since you can bless a function reference, I think I might be able to have `()->()` work with some hacking ;) .  I will be updating [here](https://github.com/cxw42/perlpp/blob/master/t/lib/TestcaseList.pm) as I work it out.

Comment: @zdim I added skips - see `LSKIP` [here](https://github.com/cxw42/perlpp/blob/prepost/t/lib/TestcaseList.pm).  I'll put it on CPAN when I get the chance.

Comment: @zdim https://metacpan.org/pod/List::AutoNumbered .  You specifically asked me to change the accept, so I am going to do so.

Comment: Great that you got around to do it!  I'll look with pleasure :)  From what I recall this actually answered the question and is now (even!) complete so it absolutely should be "the" answer, thank you for updating :)

Answer (score 3):

The `caller` can get only the line numbers of *statements*, decided at compilation.

When I change the code to

```
my @testcases;
push @testcases, ([__LINE__,0,32,'LINE']);
push @testcases, ([__LINE__,1,33,'LINE']);
push @testcases, (L(2,34,'L()'));
push @testcases, (L(3,35,'L()'));
...
```

maintaining line numbers, it works (except for string evals).

So, on the practical side, using `caller` is fine with separate statements for calls.

#### Perl internals

The line numbers are baked into the op-tree at compilation and (my emphasis)

> At run-time, only the line numbers of **statements** are available [...]

from [ikegami's post on permonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1153603).

We can see this by running `perl -MO=Concise script.pl` where the line

```
2      nextstate(main 25 line_nos.pl:45) v:*,&,{,x*,x&,x$,$,67108864 ->3
```

is for the `nextstate` op, which sets the line number for `caller` (and warnings). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28678354/4653379), and the `nextstate` example below.

A way around this would be to try to trick the compilation (somehow) or, better of course, to not assemble information in a list like that.  One such approach is in the [answer by cxw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50516105/4653379).

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50651495/4653379) for a related case and more detail.

#### `nextstate` example

Here's a multi-line function-call chain run through `Deparse` (annotated):

```
$ perl -MO=Concise -e '$x
    ->foo()
    ->bar()
    ->bat()'
d  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
1     <0> enter ->2
2     <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{ ->3    <=== the only nextstate
c     <1> entersub[t4] vKRS/TARG ->d
3        <0> pushmark s ->4
a        <1> entersub[t3] sKRMS/LVINTRO,TARG,INARGS ->b
4           <0> pushmark s ->5
8           <1> entersub[t2] sKRMS/LVINTRO,TARG,INARGS ->9
5              <0> pushmark s ->6
-              <1> ex-rv2sv sKM/1 ->7
6                 <#> gvsv[*x] s ->7
7              <.> method_named[PV "foo"] s ->8
9           <.> method_named[PV "bar"] s ->a
b        <.> method_named[PV "bat"] ->c
-e syntax OK
```

Even though successive calls are on separate lines, they are part of the same statement, so are all attached to the same `nextstate`.

Comment: zdim, good point!  I am still curious about the internal processing.  Also, `__LINE__` is shorter than `push @testcases,` :) .

Comment: @cxw  Just edited -- it apparently counts it all on one line. Like it often does -- but since these are sub calls I would've expected `caller` to see them on their own lines.

Comment: I would have also.  I found a [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50516105/2877364) that works for now, but if you ever find out why sub calls don't get their own line numbers in the `caller` record, please let me know.  Thanks for getting me thinking about alternative approaches to the problem!  You already have my upvote :) .

Comment: @cxw  Updated -- the line-number info is compiled for the **statement** where the list is given (as for more general info on why for a list and for what else ... I'll have to leave it at this for the moment).  I like your approach to get around that :)

Comment: @cxw  Thanks for adding to the answer (sorry I didn't respond right away, was hoping to first look at the problem again...)

Comment: No worries!  I just happened to get to this the other day when I was working on expanding coverage for Text::PerlPP.  If you think of anything else, would you please open an issue in List::AutoNumbered?  Thanks for taking a look at it!

Comment: @cxw I'll definitely look, but apparently I don't know when --- things just keep coming up ...

Comment: zdim, no worries - I know the feeling :)